# Unable to create Firebase Storage network request android.os.RemoteException while Retrieving Images Into RecyclerView using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

I have tried to edit my storage rules to:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm still facing this error below. I've read on existing similar posts about this but I'm still getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
09-21 12:56:07.424 2296-2296/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
                                                                                      com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg$zza: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg.zzbq(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                       Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg.zzbq(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748) 
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
09-21 12:56:09.873 2296-2296/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-21 12:56:09.942 2296-2296/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-21 12:56:15.585 2296-2456/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                                                                                              com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-21 12:56:15.585 2296-2456/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/GetMetadataTask: Unable to create firebase storage network request.
                                                                                        android.os.RemoteException
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-21 12:56:15.586 2296-2456/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                         An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                                          Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
09-21 12:56:15.586 2296-2456/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/StorageException: null
                                                                                         android.os.RemoteException
                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-21 12:56:15.615 2296-2457/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                                                                                              com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-21 12:56:15.615 2296-2457/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/GetMetadataTask: Unable to create firebase storage network request.
                                                                                        android.os.RemoteException
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-21 12:56:15.616 2296-2457/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                         An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                                          Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
09-21 12:56:15.616 2296-2457/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/StorageException: null
                                                                                         android.os.RemoteException
                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Below is my Adapter class which tries to show images into the imageView while using Picasso .

```
package oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {


  protected   Context c;
    List<ModelClass> doctors;

   public FirebaseStorage mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    StorageReference storageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com");




    public MyAdapter(Context c, List<ModelClass> doctors) {
        this.c = c;
        this.doctors = doctors;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_activity,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final  ModelClass feedItems = doctors.get(position);



        storageRef.child("askdoctor").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                System.out.println("Here is the print of url : "+uri.toString());
                Picasso.with(c).load(uri.toString()+feedItems.getPhoto())
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                        resize(50, 50)
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.img);
            }
        });

    /*    StorageReference spaceRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com/askdoctor/"+feedItems.getPhoto());
        String url = spaceRef.getPath();



        System.out.println("Here is the print of url : "+url);

                Picasso.with(c).load("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com"+url)
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                        resize(50, 50)
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.img);
*/

        holder.name.setText(doctors.get(position).getDoctorsName());
        holder.email_txt.setText(doctors.get(position).getEmail());
      // PicassoClient.downloadImage(c,doctors.get(position).getUrl(),holder.img);
        //Download image using picasso library





    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return doctors.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check your play services version... It should be latest in emulator  or device on which you are running code

Comment: Yeah my play services are up to date , do you mean i use a latest emulator of the play services version? please i am still new

Comment: Check it in real device..... Might be your device does not have it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add proper path and image extension to the child

```
storageRef.child("askdoctor/"+feedItems.getPhoto()+".png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                System.out.println("Here is the print of url : "+uri.toString());
                Picasso.with(c).load(uri.toString())
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                        resize(50, 50)
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.img);
            }
        });
```